# Create different dataframes according to a column value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

1. upi_df
2. sms_df

Dataframe sample:

```
cycle_end_date | triggered_sms | delivered_sms | event_date
2021-11-30 | 45 | 30 | 2021-12-01
2021-11-30 | 45 | 20 | 2021-12-02
2021-11-30 | 40 | 30 | 2021-12-03
2021-12-15| 4 | 3 | 2021-12-17
2021-12-15| 49 | 30 | 2021-12-18
```

All the dataframes have the same structure like this with their respective stats.

I want to create different dataframes based on `cycle_end_date`
I wrote the following code:

```
df_list = [upi_df, sms_df]
for df in df_list:
    gb = df.groupby(['cycle_end_date'])
    l = []
    for i in gb.indices:
        df = pd.DataFrame(gb.get_group(i))
        l.append(df)
```

but when i print `l[0]` I get `sms_df` stats with its 1st cycle (which is okay) but I am wondering how do I get `upi_df` stats as well of 1st cycle?

expected output:
this should be my first output

```
cycle_end_date | triggered_upi | delivered_upi | event_date
2021-11-30 | 45 | 30 | 2021-12-01
2021-11-30 | 45 | 20 | 2021-12-02
2021-11-30 | 40 | 30 | 2021-12-03

cycle_end_date | triggered_sms | delivered_sms | event_date
2021-11-30 | 45 | 30 | 2021-12-01
2021-11-30 | 45 | 20 | 2021-12-02
2021-11-30 | 40 | 30 | 2021-12-03
```

Any help?

For one df:

```
dfs_list = []
for cycle in upi_df.cycle_end_date.unique():
    temp = upi_df[upi_df.cycle_end_date==cycle]
    dfs_list.append(temp)
```

Comment: You might be looking for something like [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

Comment: Sorry I can't see what are you looking for.

Comment: I just need to create different dataframes based on unique cycle end dates for upi_df and sms_df. basically each df should have one cycle end date.

Comment: dfs_list = []
for cycle in upi_df.cycle_end_date.unique():
    temp = upi_df[upi_df.cycle_end_date==cycle]
    dfs_list.append(temp)
this way I am getting upi_df seprate dataframes. How do I create a loop for sms_df as well?

Comment: have edited my question, pls check? @SalvatoreDanieleBianco

Comment: `df_list = [g for _,g in upi_df.groupby('cycle_end_date')]`, if you need the data from another dataframe in combination, merge it first.